# Cannot run project from IntelliJ IDEA because of jdwp error

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have a project in IntelliJ IDEA I want to run locally. When I click its debug button it says:

```
ERROR: Cannot load this JVM TI agent twice, check your java command line for duplicate jdwp options.
Disconnected from server
Error occurred during initialization of VM
agent library failed to init: jdwp
```

When I click the run button it works. What is the matter?

Comment: For local app, check that you don't specified same agent twice in 'VM parameters' of config.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess you already are debugging the server app? In this case it's not possible to connect another instance of debugger.

Comment: it worked me, 10 min ago i tried with it but it did not work, now it works. thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 46):

This is probably too late to help you, but maybe it will help somebody else.  The answer is based on [a support forum posting](https://web.archive.org/web/20121113061618/http://zeroturnaround.com/forums/topic/jrebel-plugin-not-able-to-launch-jboss-in-debug-mode/) by Aleksei Sosnovski.

This can happen when your `JAVA_OPTS` contains two `-Xrunjdwp` arguments. E.g., one of these arguments might come from the server start script invoked by IntelliJ to start the container, and another may be added by IntelliJ itself. You can check by looking at `JAVA_OPTS` in the log when launching the container without debug. If you see an `-Xrunjdwp` argument, just find where it is set in the container startup script, and remove it.

Comment: Thanks its work for me and i found startup script in Intellij under JBoss -> Edit Configuration -> Startup/Connection -> Startup script and removed -Xrunjdwp line

Answer (score 4):

Most likely the problem happens because you have specified the debugging options in the "VM parameters" field of your run configuration. Everything will work if you remove them.

Comment: Removing the duplicate debugging configuration helped. Thanks @yole.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem in my case `-Xrunjdwp` was set twice: one in the IDEA debug configuration and again in the system variables in `CATAALINA_OPTS`.

once I removed it from system variables (inside the IDEA it is read only) problem was fixed

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the tips, it helped me work out the problem too.  Mine was due to having
    set DEBUG_OPTS=-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005

In my catalina.bat

Answer (score 1):

1. check **server.xml** if you have **jvmEntries**  get rid of that entry from server.xml

   ```
   <!-- <jvmEntries xmi:id="JavaVirtualMachine_1" classpath="" bootClasspath="" verboseModeClass="false" verboseModeGarbageCollection="false" verboseModeJNI="false" runHProf="false" hprofArguments="" debugMode="false" debugArgs="-Djava.compiler=NONE -Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=7777" genericJvmArguments="">
   ```
2. Open admin console (http://localhost:9060/ibm/console/login.do)

   ***Application servers > server1 > Debugging service***

   un-check Enable service at server startup if checked restart server.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

On Intellij uncheck the 'Pass environment variables' box in Run/Debug configuration

[image: Run/Debug configuration screenshot]